# C++; MPI: Send struct with vector of vectors through MPI

Tags: c++, vector, struct, mpi

I'm trying to send this structure through MPI, but I don't know if that's right.

```
struct Node {
int sum_node;
int depth_node;
vector<vector<int> > subset;
vector<int> sum_subset;
vector<int> depth_subset;
};
```

Sending like this:

```
Node zz = stack.back();
stack.pop_back();
MPI_Send(&zz, sizeof(struct Node), MPI_BYTE, 1, MSG_WORK_SENT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Receiving like this:

```
Node gg;
MPI_Recv(&gg, sizeof(struct Node), MPI_BYTE, status.MPI_SOURCE, MSG_WORK_SENT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
stack.push_back(gg);
```

And program terminated with Segmentation fault.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Please show us the segmentation fault backtrace ...

Comment: Remember that internally, `std::vector` will have a pointer to a chunk of memory that will lie outside of a `Node` instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending non-POD data over MPI which is not correct.
You need to serialize/deserialize the whole Node during send/receive work.

For example, if I have a node and I have 1000 elements in its sum_subset, now you only send sizeof(Node) over:

```
  Node d;
  for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
  {
    d.sum_subset.push_back(1);
  }
  cout << sizeof(Node) << endl;
```

checkout http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html for more information

Comment: Thank you, I will have to serialize my struct. I will do it into vector which I should send through MPI.

Comment: «You are sending non-POD data over MPI which is not correct» You mean that although sending a vector<int> works, it's not correct?